# Why is this SQL statement (SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=2) returning only the first instance?

Tags: php, sql

I have the following table:

```
items:
id |color| price
1   red   10
2   red   11
2   blue  11.5
3   green 9
```

id and color make up the key.
i want to return all items with id=2.

I tried using this statement

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=2
```

but the output is only

```
Array([id] => 2 [color] => red [price]=>11)
```

Why doesnt it return both of the items of id = 2 (the red and blue) as expected? How do I return all items with id=2??

Comment: Are you sure this is reproducible, because it doesn't look like it is.

Comment: Could you also post the PHP code you are using. Maybe you are only fetching once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most likely you are using

```
fetch(); //which Fetches the next row from a result set
```

instead of

```
fetchALL(); //which Returns an array containing all of the result set rows
```

if this is not the case please edit your question and add your complete code

Comment: This solved it! I was using a prepared statement and had the command fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), changed it to fetchAll and its working as expected. Thanks!!!

Comment: I assumed the id in the table is not the primary key but it’s foreign key and you have another column for primary key. As both people have mentioned that was confusing and something was missing. If you don’t have a primary key in this table so you might need to reconsider the structure of your table

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible because a primary key is unique so you should only have one item with the id of 2.